# Regex not working with mysql's REGEXP

Tags: mysql, regex

**Problem:**

I want to get all records that contain a subdomain.

Some subdomains are saved prefixed with `www.` after the `http://`, but not all are.

**Examples**:

`http://www.sub.domain.com` and `http://sub.domain.com`

I have this **working** regex that I have tested on [RegExr](http://www.regexr.com/):

`^(http:\/\/)(www\.)?(\w)+(\.)(\w)+(.)(\w|\/){2,10}`

Which matches both examples nicely.

However when I try using this regex in my query using `REGEXP`, mysql returns 0 records.

**I have tried:**

```
SELECT * FROM `front` WHERE `domain` REGEXP '^(http:\/\/)(www\.)?(\w)+(\.)(\w)+(\.)(\w|\/){2,10}$';

SELECT * FROM `front` WHERE `domain` REGEXP '/^(http:\/\/)(www\.)?(\w)+(\.)(\w)+(\.)(\w|\/){2,10}$/';

SELECT * FROM `front` WHERE `domain` REGEXP '/^(http:\/\/)(www\.)?(\w)+(\.)(\w)+(\.)(\w|\/){2,10}$/g';
```

Which all return 0 records.

**TL;DR**

My working REGEX does not seem to be working when used in MySQL's `REGEXP` function.

Comment: What I usually do in these situations is try to gradually build up the regex. Start out with a simple one that matches a superset of the rows you need and then slowly add more parts of it. You will eventually figure out which part is causing it to fail

Comment: Well the problem is that the regex works! It just doesn't work when putting it through mysql's REGEXP function. I will update my answer to be clearer about this.

Comment: The fact that it works on http://www.regexr.com/ is not very relevant. MySQL might not support the same set of regex features that the website does. Try building it in MySQL from scratch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no `\w` metacharacter support in MySQL. Use `[A-Za-z0-9_]` instead:

```
SELECT * FROM `front` WHERE `domain` REGEXP '^(http:\/\/)(www\.)?([A-Za-z0-9_])+(\.)([A-Za-z0-9_])+(.)([A-Za-z0-9_]|\/){2,10}$';
```

Comment: This was it! I atleast got records back now, looks like I still need to tweak the REGEX abit though. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

It's right there in [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html):

> Because MySQL uses the C escape syntax in strings (for example, “\n” to represent the newline character), you must double any “\” that you use in your REGEXP strings.